# Old client's SSL certificate and new certificate with same pub/private key

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, x509, public-key, der

**Situation:** we can't update `der` file on the client's device. And the SSL certificate on our web server expires soon.

Is it possible to renew the server's SSL certificate without replacing the client's certificate?

We want to follow this guide: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/how-to-issue-a-new-ssl-certificate-with-an-old-ssl-key/

However, we are not sure if it helps.

**The question is:**

Does the `der` file (on the client side) contain only public key and it is safe to renew SSL certificate using the technique described in the link above (keeping same pub/private keys).

Will it work on client's device without replacing `der` file? Or `der` file contains not only the public key for SSL certificate but also some other information?

Comment: It is unclear what is the certificate on client device? Client authentication certificate? Public copy of server certificate? Can you elaborate this?

Comment: it's a `der` file used to establish SSL pinning in the iOS app. I think it's public copy if server's certificate. If you open the website in Firefox and download the certificate - it is the exact same file.

Comment: How pinning validation is performed? Based on exact match (when comparing binary copies of certificates) or base on key match only (when only public key portion is compared)?

Comment: I'll try to understand myself from code, but a quick response is: 
// Establish a chain of trust anchored on our bundled certificate.
    CFArrayRef certArrayRef = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (void *)&cert, 1, NULL);
    SecTrustRef serverTrust = protectionSpace.serverTrust;
    SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates(serverTrust, certArrayRef);
    
    // Verify that trust.
    SecTrustResultType trustResult;
    SecTrustEvaluate(serverTrust, &trustResult);

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid, but based on your original post and clarifications, client will expect from web server **the same** server certificate as stored in DER file on client device. Client performs exact binary copy comparison (not only public keys).

Any attempts to replace server certificate will result in a connection failure on client. If you plan to replace the certificate on web server, you will have to update client devices as well.

Unfortunately, there are a lot of flawed HPKP implementations (to be honest, didn't see any reliable implementation) that work fine until server certificate is changed. In order to properly handle server certificate replacement, client **MUST be able to store at least two server certificates**, existing and new one. Here is the high-level server certificate replacement process:

1. acquire new server certificate from CA in advance.
2. make application update by including new certificate side-by-side. When client updates the application on their device, client app will trust both, existing and new certificate.
3. give clients a time to make app update on their devices. Ideally, you should wait until all clients have updated app version with updated certificate.
4. change SSL certificate in server bindings.
5. after aa time you can make another update for client certificate by removing expired certificate from trust store.

only this step sequence may guarantee uninterrupted certificate pinning renewal.

Comment: Thank you! I've checked and you are right. SecTrustEvaluate checks the certificate file, not the public keys (https://opensource.apple.com//source/Security/Security-55471/libsecurity_keychain/lib/SecTrust.cpp - I'm not proficient in cpp, but looks like this is true). So I have to update `der` file on client's device :(

Comment: I agree with your way on how to replace SSL certs. But for people that are looking at this answer and who wants to implement SSL pinning on iOS, would be nice to know that there is another way - compare public keys. Check this article for more details: https://www.bugsee.com/blog/ssl-certificate-pinning-in-mobile-applications/

Comment: Public key pinning will still require proper implementation, because public keys are changed too.